# Headphones are detected as input device when plugged (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones

I'm new to Linux and I'm having trouble getting my headphones to work.

When I plug my headphones into my Dell Inspiron laptop's 3.5 mm headphone jack, the sound keeps coming from the speaker instead of the headphones. Also, the Input section in the Sound settings changes from "Internal microphone" to "Microphone" and the Output section keeps showing "Speaker" instead of "Headphones."

This was happening the first time I booted after installing Ubuntu, then I restarted and the headphones were detected and worked correctly, but now I restarted again and the issue is back.

I practically found no article on this specific issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
I just found out that, if I turn off my laptop and turn it back on, then the headphones jack is  recognized and works normally. However, it stops working after reboot/sleep.

Comment: Your headphones and speakers might be linked in Ubuntu sound settings. [Try this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190212/553502).

Answer (score 1):

I have dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10 and I realized that the problem only happens when I reboot from Windows into Ubuntu. If I shut down the laptop and then  boot straight into Ubuntu, the headphones are recognized correctly.